# Can you wait to define a function until the onload event?

Tags: javascript, load, onload

First of all, I'm mostly wondering whether or not you can use `window.onload` to define a `function` without actually running it until a `<button>` is clicked.

I have some apps that I have designed in JavaScript, and some of them are designed for specific sites that I use, but on those sites I have trouble allowing other users the option to use my apps without making the page take forever to load for some of them. You can find my apps at http://jsfiddle.net/kaloncpu57/B9wCn/ but I don't think the problem lies within my apps (unless you can find a way to condense them down to almost nothing).

Also, for reference, the sites that I'm having the trouble on are wapka.mobi sites like http://3dsflare.wapka.mobi if you want to actually head there to test solutions (you'll need to register).

To allow the other users access to my apps, I put the external script in my Signature along with a `<button>` to run them (I realize how much of a security issue it is to allow scripts in signatures, and trust me, it gets exploited all the time). The users that are having issues are using devices that don't support the `defer` attribute for external scripts, and after many attempts the only solution I have left is to use `window.onload` to load the function for each app after everything else loads, but just using `window.onload = function`... just runs the `function` of course.

Is it possible to wait until the page is loaded to define a `function`, or does anybody have any other solutions? Thanks in advance for any helpful information.

Comment: One huge paragraph is not readable.

Comment: @epascarello How's that?

Comment: do you mean `$(document).ready(function{});` ?

Comment: @plalx I asked my question at the end, and mentioned it at the beginning.

Comment: Can you define functions on window onload...yes...

Comment: @kaloncpu57 Well to me it's still very unclear. However I can assure you that you can define a function on `window.onload` just like you would define a function anywhere else. You can also load script tags dynamically when appropriate.

Comment: @plalx I know that you can use `window.onload = function foo()` but that runs the `function` and I just want it to define the function without running it. Also, I said that the `defer` attribute for `<script>` tags is not a workable solution for me, and I forgot to mention that the same goes for the `async` attribute.

Comment: You can add a script element whenever you like using `document.createElement('script')`, setting the `src` property and appending it somewhere in the document head or body.

Comment: @kaloncpu57 you can always define  a function without running it. by defining it meaning it is ready for use when it is triggered by an event

Comment: @kaloncpu57 Do you mean this? `window.onload = function () {  myGlobalFunction = function () {}; };`

Comment: @RobG You bring up something else I forgot to mention. On the sites that I am concerned with, any form of quotes are escaped even though you can use HTML in the signature. Attributes for any tags do not require quotes, but you have to make sure not to use spaces in the attributes. That means I need some external script no matter what, right from the start.

Comment: @ejay_francisco Right, but just defining the functions is enough to slow down the page dramatically for the other users when the `<script>` is in a signature , which is where I have to have it since I have no control over anything else.

Comment: @plalx `window.onload = function () { myGlobalFunction = function()` Is `myGlobalFunction` really global? Could I call it from a `<button>`?

Comment: @kaloncpu57 Yes, it's a global function. Just attach it has an event handler of the `click` event of the `<button>`. You actually do not have to declare the function globally to do this and usually should avoid polluting the global scope.

Comment: *"First of all, I'm mostly wondering whether or not you can use `window.onload` to define a function without actually running it until a `<button>` is clicked. "* Absolutely. You don't even have a to use `window.onload`. **Defining** a function does not execute it. *"but just using window.onload = function... just runs the function of course. "* Well, it runs the function on page load, it does not run the function when you assign it to `.onload`. I think I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling It still takes time to load it without actually running though, or at least that's what I'm seeing on the site I'm using.

Comment: Yes, some time will be spent to parse the code and create the function objects. Are you saying that that is taking too long? You seem to have only 344 lines of code, that should not be an issue at all.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, many other users are complaining that the page takes minutes to load anything that appears after my signature.

Comment: What do you mean by "signature"? Your code? That sounds like an rather odd behavior. Changing how your code is loaded might be a workaround, but I'd argue that there is a "real" solution to that problem. However, I don't think that this can be fixed via SO, at least not with the information you have given.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I guess I forgot to fully explain that. The "signature" is a signature in the forums. It's what is displayed at the bottom of every post I make on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this [blog](http://javascript.about.com/library/blfastpage.htm) about how a page can load faster

specially this part :

for example you have this on your `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript2.js"></script>
```

change it to :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fastload.js"></script>
```

then in fastload.js :

```
function addJavascript(jsname) {
var th = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
th.appendChild(s);
}
addJavascript('myscript1.js');
addJavascript('myscript2.js');
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Sadly, it's looking like any external scripts are causing the loading problems. I guess I will just have to give up on this. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have some .gif images that are timing out and delaying the load event by about 15 seconds.

Comment: I'm sure the .gif images are slowing things down I'm sure, but I'm trying on other wapka.mobi sites as well where Forum CSS is not an option, and the load time is still an issue. The reason I linked to that site is that the signature has no character limit.

Comment: ...but in this case, anything you have in `window.onload` is going to wait for those .gif images to load, even though the rest of the DOM was ready--and could have executed--15 seconds ago. Your console's [profiler](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) can be great tool for stuff like this.